# WebAPI RC GetAll with URI parameters

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Previously in WebAPI (beta) I was able to create a "GetAll" method that took in optional parameters added on the URI:

```
http://localhost/api/product?take=5&skip=10
```

This still seems to work but only if I include all the parameters.  In (beta), I could omit the parameters ( `http://localhost/api/product/` ) and the "GetAll" method would get called (take & skip would be null).  I could also omit some of the parameters `http://localhost/api/product?take=5` (skip would be null)

```
public IEnumerable<ProductHeaderDto> GetAll(int? take, int? skip)
{
    var results = from p in productRepository
                  select new ProductHeaderDto
                    {
                        Id = p.Id,
                        Version = p.Version,
                        Code = p.Code,
                        Description = p.DescriptionInternal,
                        DisplayName = p.Code + " " + p.DescriptionInternal
                    };
    if (skip != null) results = results.Skip(skip.Value);
    if (take != null) results = results.Take(take.Value);
    return results;
}
```

In (RC), I now get "No action was found on the controller 'Product' that matches the request." when both or one of the parameters are missing.  I have tried adding [FromUri] on the method parameters but that has no affect:

```
public IEnumerable<ProductHeaderDto> GetAll([FromUri] int? take, [FromUri] int? skip)
```

I have also tried setting default values:

```
public IEnumerable<ProductHeaderDto> GetAll(int? take = null, int? skip = null)
```

Is there some sort of "optional" parameter attribute that could be used when trying to match the method signature?

Comment: Do you have any other action Method which corresponds to GET in the controller

Comment: I have decided to use the excellent AttributeRouting library - https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting/wiki .  By explicitly defining the URIs I am able to get everything going with great granularity. When using this, the issue with "nullable" parameters goes away and the controller behaves as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug which has been fixed in RTM. You can have optional parameter by specifying default value.

```
public IEnumerable<string> Get(int? take = null, int? skip = null)
```

BTW, you can use $skip and $top in [web api odata package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData) to achieve the same functions.

Comment: The OData package is great but would require me to expose my Entities directly. This is a problem as our entities do not always serialize and it isn't generally recommended to expose entities directly.  For some solutions it is great.