# Api method path wont route

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Im trying to get this method to route and hit a breakpoint, but the route isnt found.

In WebApi.config:

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

My API method that lives in a controller called UserController

```
/// <summary>
/// Get specific user 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="username"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
[HttpGet]
public string GetUserInfo(string username)
{
    string retval = username;
    return retval;
}
```

Then I try to make the call with a path like this
http://localhost:59023/api/User/GetUserInfo/testuser

but the method isnt being found. I get a message in the browser like this:
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:59023/api/User/GetUserInfo/testuser'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route configuration defines a parameter "id", but your action method accepts a parameter called "username". 
Change one or the other so that they are the same (both username or both id).

Comment: Thats it, thank you!  Now I need to expand my review of routing a bit more it seems.

Comment: No problem. Take a look at Attribute Routing (or Direct routing). I find it easier to configure and manage.

Comment: Actually, I think I can just remove the {id} part of the route config and use parameterized values on the querystring, correct?  This is the direction Im headed anyway since I will need to handle skip/take paging operations on other methods.  I was reviewing this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640639/webapi-rc-getall-with-uri-parameters)

Comment: It's really a matter of taste. What I like is to put mandatory parameters, like an id as part of the url pattern and extra optional parameters, like paging, as query string parameters. For example, I would do api/customer/33/orders?skip=20&take=10